# Skinning MFC scrollbar

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, mfc

***Premise***: I need to change the colors of the default `CScrollBar` defined in MFC (thumb + track + arrows), but after doing some research I realized that this isn't exactly an easy task.

***Question***: would it be better if I tried to draw OVER the existing scrollbar, or should I create a new scrollbar control from scratch?

- If I limited myself to drawing on it, I would have the advantage of not having to manage all the messages that deal with the other features of the scrollbar (in addition to the drawing), but it is VERY complicated to find all the points where windows redraws the bar, since the scrollbar is not redrawn only in the `OnPaint()` method.
- If I redo it from scratch, I would no longer have the problem of identifying all the points where the bar is redrawn ... but on the other hand I should reimplement all the scrollbar features from scratch.

I've already looked at this link:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14724/Replace-a-Window-s-Internal-Scrollbar-with-a-custo
but the proposed method does not seem to work for newer versions of Windows (from Vista onwards).

Any advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorscrollbar?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

Comment: WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR is absolutely incomplete. You cannot change the colors of all scrollbar elements by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had exactly the same problem and your attempt to overdraw the original scrollbar was what we tried first. We dropped that attempt again due to some issues, which I don't remember in detail (not receiving all mouse or draw messages, flickering, ...). Our solution was some effort, but works now:

We implemented first a class CCustomScrollBar, which is NOT derived from CScrollBar, because the CScrollBar is just a wrapper around the Windows implementation and overwriting OnPaint() doesn't work perfect. And yes, all things must be implemented from scratch.

Second we implemented a template class CWndCustomScrollBar keeping two CCustomScrollBars and managing all around them as a standard window would do with its embedded scrollbars. The free client area then can be achieved via a method GetClientRectWithoutScrollBar() to work similar as a standard window would do.

Comment: I was afraid that redoing the bar from scratch and re-implementing all the features from scratch was the best solution ... thanks a lot for the explanation/example, I think I'll use your approach.